# Lanzar Aplicaciones Desde El Navegador?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Buen dia, Tengo la siguiente duda hace ya varios dias estoy intentando abrir aplicaciones que tenga instalado el cliente 
desde el navegador, Tal como se aprecian en las imagenes adjuntas (Esto lo probe desde Google Chrome) 
(Esta funcionalidad es del BitBucket) donde abre 
SourceTree Siempre con una confirmacion del cliente si desea hacerlo o no.

He leido sobre como hacerlo y por lo que vi siempre son respuestas negativas (No se puede) y otros han planteado soluciones
con ActiveX o applets de los cuales el ActiveX Al parecer solo son soportados por Internet Explorer y/o otros exploradores
con un pluging "Simulando" el estar en internet Explorer lo cual no me parece una solucion poco adecuada y los applets al parecer
dejaron de ser soportados en los navegadores a partir del 2015 por motivos de seguridad

Alguna Recomendacion de como lograr esta funcionalidad debido a que no puedo limitar
a mis usuarios a unicamente IE , cualquier idea es bien recibida!, Muchas Gracias[image: ![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUFKN.png)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Davis, te saludo y te sugiero la importancia de leer [ask] para la realización de preguntas, por favor no olvides realizar el [tour] para que entiendas su funcionamiento, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

## Respuesta corta:

No se puede

---

## Alternativas

Se pueden explotar las *URI'S*, gracias a las especificacines de [*URI*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) y [*HTML*](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5), los enlaces `a` permiten colocar *URI's* y no solo *URL's* a su vez la especificación *URI* permite infinidad de protocolos (llamados esquemas)

Los navegadores modernos si detectan un protocolo que ellos no entiendan buscan en el sistema operativo si existe algún programa que sí lo haga, de existir, entonces lo ejecuta y envía la URI completa al programa como parámetro.

Un programa accesible desde web **DEBE**:

1. Registar su esquema en el sistema operativo objetivo
2. Colocar enlaces a su programa a través de la etiqueta `a`

## TL;TR

En el caso de windows es posible registrar un nuevo esquema y asignarle un programa especifico desde el Registro de Windows

Por ejemplo para crear el uri scheme *cmd* accesible desde el navegador a través de `cmd:foo` donde `foo` es el programa a ejecutar se debe agregar las siguientes entradas al registro:

cmd.reg

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROT\cmd]
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROT\cmd\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROT\cmd\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROT\cmd\shell\open\command]
@="cmd /k \"echo %1\""
```

### Instalando cmd.reg

1. Click derecho
2. Combinar

[image: combinando cmd.reg]

3. Aceptar cualquier alerta

[image: exito al instalarse]

### Probándolo

```html
<a href="cmd:echo hola mundo">Abrir consola</a>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

**Nota:**
Si bien se puede acceder a cmd desde `cmd:comando` no es que realmente se ejecute el comando. Para ejecutar realmente el comando primero se necesita decodificar la url que se recibe ya que se recibirá una url codificada con la notación `%` así `cmd:echo hola mundo` el navegador enviará a nuestro controlador `cmd:echo%20hola%20mundo`

Más información sobre cómo registrar esquemas en el sistema operativo objetivo

- [Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx)
- Linux

  - [gnome](http://people.w3.org/%7Edom/archives/2005/09/integrating-a-new-uris-scheme-handler-to-gnome-and-firefox/)
  - [kde](https://superuser.com/questions/91611/picasa-links-in-google-chrome-linux/93419#93419)