# ¿Es posible ejecutar un .exe desde un servicio web alojado en un servidor iis?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webservice

Quería saber si hay alguna forma de poder ejecutar un `.exe` desde un servicio web c# , tengo el servicio ya hecho y funcionando pero quisiera agregarle el código que esta mas abajo para generar un archivo `.txt`. Pero no se si es posible o si solo bastaría con agregar el código al servicio.

```
string command = "C:\\Generar\\Generador.exe " + FechaArchivo(fecha) + "";
ExecuteCommand(command);

static string ExecuteCommand(string _Command)
{
    //Indicamos que deseamos inicializar el proceso cmd.exe junto a un comando de arranque. 
    //(/C, le indicamos al proceso cmd que deseamos que cuando termine la tarea asignada se cierre el proceso).
    //Para mas informacion consulte la ayuda de la consola con cmd.exe /? 
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + _Command);
    // Indicamos que la salida del proceso se redireccione en un Stream
    procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    //Indica que el proceso no despliegue una pantalla negra (El proceso se ejecuta en background)
    procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
    //Inicializa el proceso
    System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
    proc.Start();
    //Consigue la salida de la Consola(Stream) y devuelve una cadena de texto
    string result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    return result;
    //Muestra en pantalla la salida del Comando
    //Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Comment: ¿Hiciste alguna prueba de tu servicio invocando al ejecutable? ¿Se debe ejecutar de lado servidor o cliente?

Comment: Sí realice una prueba antes pero esta no ejecutó el exe, la aplicación debe ejecutarse en el cliente pero la instrucción se envía desde el servidor.

Comment: El cliente tiene el exe en su equipo? De todas maneras dudo que sea posible de manera sencilla, debido a que por seguridad el navegador no tiene acceso al equipo en el que esta corriendo

Comment: @JaphSxas al invocar tu **servicio web** solo lo ejecutaría del lado servidor. La manera como lo expones tu servicio NUNCA va a ejecutar de lado cliente. Quizás quieras revisar una pregunta [Lanzar Aplicaciones Desde El Navegador?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/127617/45), donde indica el cómo se podría ejecutar una aplicación desde el navegador.

Comment: pues hasta donde lo has planteado implica muchos riesgos de seguridad, pero para entender tu problema... para que quieres crear un archivo? por que no regresarlo al dar click en una liga y que el usuario elija donde se guarda? si eso no basta ya has probado con ClickOnce Deployment? (He oído que es el equivalente de Java Web Start pero no lo he usado porque todo lo que huele a C# huele históricamente a robado )